# Need to adjust how an action works

Tags: acumatica

I have to adjust how an action works. I know that I cannot adjust the code that runs the action itself, so is there any way to execute extra code when a specific action has been executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply declare the Action in your extension the same as the base action to "override"

Here is an example overriding the View Source Document action on GL Journal Entry:

```
public class JournalEntryMyExtension : PXGraphExtension<JournalEntry>
{
    public PXAction<Batch> viewDocument;
    [PXLookupButton]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "View Source Document", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
    public virtual IEnumerable ViewDocument(PXAdapter adapter)
    {
        // Logic Before Base Action

        Base.viewDocument.Press(adapter);

        // Logic After Base Action

        return adapter.Get();
    }
}
```

Here is the action direct from the base graph for comparison:

```
public PXAction<Batch> viewDocument;
[PXUIField(DisplayName = Messages.ViewSourceDocument, MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select, MapViewRights = PXCacheRights.Select)]
[PXLookupButton()]
public virtual IEnumerable ViewDocument(PXAdapter adapter)
{
    if (this.GLTranModuleBatNbr.Current != null)
    {
        GLTran tran = (GLTran) this.GLTranModuleBatNbr.Current;

        OpenDocumentByTran(tran, BatchModule.Current);
    }

    return adapter.Get();
}
```

Comment: Alright, I'll give this a try.  Thanks a ton Brendan!

Comment: Brendan, I may have made this question too general for my specific issue. Your answer looks correct, but of course I'm trying to adjust something that isn't a normal action. I'm working on adjusting how Create Shipment works in SOOrderEntry, but it seems like that action has its own BLC: SOCreateShipment. I'm going to look into that. If you've dealt with adjusting this specific action in the past, advice would be welcomed.

Comment: In that case you can just do a graph extension on SOShipmentEntry and PXOverride on CreateShipment. Run your code either before or after calling the base delegate. Hope that helps

Comment: Yep, I believe that is what I need to do. I was looking in the wrong place. I should have been looking in SOShipmentEntry as you had mentioned. Thanks a ton Brendan!

Comment: If I wanted to override the PXButton Action in SOOrder, would I need to set it up any different due to the fact there are a ton more variables to that button, multiple action definitions within the button's function, a list that is populated through the function and returned?

Comment: without diving in to deep i am not sure, but i think many of those buttons call methods that themselves allow for you to override in the graph using [PXOverride]

Comment: Alright, thanks anyway. I think what the customer wants me to do may not be possible due to multiple reasons regarding that action including a popup and how it is constructed. It isn't an absolutely necessary feature, but more one that was just a quality of life addition.